# Ruby 1.9.2, mysql, json, rails, and non-ascii characters not handled

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have for example the following json:

```
{"header":"Châteauneuf du Pape, Féraud Brunel, 2007", "detail":null}
```

and am bringing this in via following code in my seeds.rb:

```
u=IO.read(file)
m=JSON.parse(u)
```

I create my Rails model objects. The issue is that the a circumflex and e accent aren't inserted correctly and I get back a question mark. When I puts the object, the accent is there. If I copy and save from this output and look at the hex

If I start a rails console and create a new object:

```
i=Item.new :header_id => 365
i.header='here are ü and ê and à'
i.save
```

and verify

```
select * from items where id=1299;
id: 1299
header: here are ü and ê and à
```

What would be the next place to look? Do I need to force Rails to think that the JSON it is getting is UTF-8? Shouldn't it be knowing that it is already?

thx

Comment: For .rb files you normally add the magic comment `# encoding: utf-8` at the top of the file to tell Ruby that the file is UTF-8. I'm not sure whether that works for your type of file. Otherwise you should ensure that the file is UTF-8.